# Viewstate of UserControl failing to load after migrating 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: user-controls, viewstate

I have a gridview and a usercontrol. On Rowediting event i am binding details in usercontrol. But when any postback happens inside that usecontrol, then following excetion generates.

"Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request"

The code was working fine with framework version2.0. After migrating our website to framework version 4.0 this is not working

Note: I am not adding/replacing controls dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now. The problem was i was opening user control in row editing event and was not actually editing the row.  i placed e.cancel=true; in row editing event which solved this issue

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~